# Curl FTP Upload only Modified / Changed Files

Tags: bash, curl, ftp

i wrote a bash script to deploy the relevant files to my web server.
I use curl for the upload mainly because it was pre installed on my mac.

It works fine but i don't want to upload all the files with the deployment because every file is transferred one by one. I did some research in the API documentation of the curl program and on google as well but i did not find any information about an option which let me set curl to only upload modified files.

Has anyone an idea how i can archive this with curl?

```
#!/bin/bash
recurse() {
 if [ -z ${var+x} ]; then
    dir=$1
 fi
 for i in "$1"/*;do
    if [ -d "$i" ];then
        echo "dir: $i"
        dir=$i
        recurse "$i"
    elif [ -f "$i" ]; then
        curl --ftp-create-dirs -T $i ftp://server/$dir/ --user username:password
        echo "file: $i"
    fi
 done
}

recurse stylesheets
recurse js
recurse bower_components
curl --ftp-create-dirs -T index.html ftp://server/$dir/ --user username:password
```

This code loops through my stylesheets / js / bower_components folders and creates all subfolders and uploads all files.

Comment: Can you maybe use `rsync`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As @MarkSetchell suggested, using `rsync` could work. But you should really post your code so we can see what your program is trying to accomplish.

Comment: agree with both comments. Also, see if you have `lftp` installed. I believe it has `mirror` mode that provides your requirement. Good luck.